# Getting parameter values in the scope of another function

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to get the variables of read input into the scope of calculate seats. Despite how I declare the variables short of re-defining them; rows, columns, and the array seatingChart cannot seem to be found by the function calculateSeats.

*** Added calculateSeats(seatingChart[rows][columns]); ***

```
int main() {

    int seatsSold = 0, oneSeat = 0, seatsTogether = 0, threeSeats = 0, fourSeats = 0, fiveSeats = 0, noSeats = 0, totalSold = 0, 
    rows, columns, pecentageSold, i;
    const int SIZE = 50;
    char seatingChart[SIZE][SIZE];

    readInput(rows, columns, seatingChart[rows][columns]); // Call read input.

    // Values of read input are then passed to calculate values. 
    calculateSeats(seatsSold, oneSeat, seatsTogether, threeSeats, fourSeats, fiveSeats, noSeats, i);

    // Calculated valus are then declared as calculated values and passed to write output. 

    /* int calculatedValues = calculateSeats(seatsSold, oneSeat = 0, seatsTogether = 0, threeSeats = 0, 
                                          fourSeats = 0, fiveSeats = 0, noSeats = 0); */

    // Function is called to write the output.
    writeOutput(seatsSold, oneSeat, seatsTogether, threeSeats, fourSeats, fiveSeats, noSeats, pecentageSold, totalSold); 

    return 0; // Program ends.
}

// Function is needed for assigning values to the char array. Values are then passed from read to calculate. 
int readInput(int & rows, int & columns, int i) {

    const int SIZE = 50;
    int seatingChart[SIZE][SIZE];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("SeatingChart.txt");
    for (rows; rows < SIZE; rows++) { // Step through the valueless array and give the array values.
        for (columns; columns < SIZE; columns++)
            inputFile >> seatingChart[rows][columns]; // Assign the array values from the input file. 
    }
    inputFile.close();

    calculateSeats(seatingChart[rows][columns]);

    return 0;
}

// Function is needed just for calculations. Values are then passed from calculate to write output. 
void calculateSeats(int & seatsSold, int & oneSeat, int & seatsTogether, int & threeSeats, 
                    int & fourSeats, int & fiveSeats, int & noSeats, int & sixSeats) {

    for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++) { // Step back through the array with loaded values. 
        for (int num = 0; num < columns; num++) {

            // If equal to A and count is equal to count++. Then consecutive read chars is true.
            if (seatingChart[count][num] == 'A' && seatingChart[count][num] == seatingChart[count][num]++) {
                seatsTogether++;

                    if (seatsTogether > 1) {
                        threeSeats++;

                    if (seatsTogether > 2) {
                        fourSeats++;
                    }

                    if (seatsTogether > 3) {
                        fiveSeats++;
                    }

                    if (seatsTogether > 4) {
                        sixSeats++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                seatsSold++;
                cout << "Total seats sold: " << seatsSold << endl;
                if (seatsSold == 6) {
                    cout << "Rows with no seats available: " << "row" << seatingChart[count] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the c++ container classes (like `std::vector`) is likely to save you a lot of headaches. So I would strongly recommend that you look into using those. Additionally all the variables that relate to seats seem to be connected, if this is the case it makes a lot of sense to logically group those variables in your code by using a `struct`. Also if you don't change variables that you are passing in as references then you probably should either be passing them by const reference or perhaps by value.

Comment: Why would a vector be more efficient than an array?

Comment: It comes down to programmer efficiency, passing a vector is extremely easy and you currently are having problems getting your program to compile at all. Make your programs correct before you worry about the efficiency of a raw array vs `std::vector`. This c++ FAQ entry is good summary of my thoughts on this matter: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html If you need to make the array version you have here work then you will need to return the array from readInput then pass the array as a pointer to the calculateSeats function (or sub-optimally you could make it a global variable)

Comment: Create a class, store the data as member variables, move the functions to be member functions and then they can easily access the data. Object oriented languages work better when you take the time to identify the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring rows, columns and seating chart in the scope of main.
This variables lay on the stack. If you want  them to make visible in readInput you have to declare them as globals. So it should look like this.

```
int row, column;
char seatingChart[SIZE][SIZE];

int main()
{   
//your code
}
```

Globals are considered as bad style.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Comment: I've been told no global variables, but thank you. I guess I just don't completely understand passing variables yet. So is there no simple resolution to my problem?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use globals than you have to pass them to the function. 
calculateSeats has already 8 parameter which is not a good style.
I suggest you declare two structs one where you centralize the seat parameter and an other one for row, column ans seatingChart.

Comment: I suggest you read the wikipedia article about structs.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)